# Automate the Boring Stuff Chapter 10 - Selective Copy by file extension

Tags: python, file-system

The [project outline](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter10/):

> Write a program that walks through a folder tree and searches for
> files with a certain file extension (such as .pdf or .jpg). Copy these
> files from whatever location they are in to a new folder.

My solution:

```
import os, shutil
from pathlib import Path

def copy_extension(basedir, newdir, extension):
    for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(basedir):
        for filename in filenames:
            if not filename.endswith(extension):
                continue
            file_path = Path(foldername) / Path(filename)
            destination = newdir / filename
            if destination.exists():
                new_destination = copy_increment(destination)
                shutil.copy(file_path, new_destination)
            else: 
                shutil.copy(file_path, destination)

def copy_increment(destination):
    marker = 0
    stem, extension = os.path.splitext(destination)
    while destination.exists():
        marker += 1
        destination = Path(f"{stem} ({marker}){extension}")
    return destination

def main():
    while True:
        user_search = input("Please enter a folder to search: ")
        basedir = Path(user_search)
        if not basedir.is_dir():
            print("This path does not exist.")
            continue
        else:
            user_destination = input("Please enter a the director of the new folder: ")
            newdir = Path(user_destination)
            extension = input("Extension of files to copy: ")
            copy_extension(basedir, newdir, extension)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Besides what has already been pointed out in the answers, I would replace the complexity of dealing with user input by using an existing CLI library like [fire](https://github.com/google/python-fire) or [click](https://github.com/pallets/click). Personally, I like `fire` more, as it is simpler. But `click` allows for more customisation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Old style -vs- new style

You are mixing old-style `os.` operations and the newer `pathlib.Path` functions.  Pick one ... specifically the newer version.

For instance, `os.walk()`, and subsequent filtering (such as by extension) can easily be replaced with just `Path.rglob()`:

```
    source = Path(source_path)
    for src in source.rglob("*.txt"):
        # process the `src` file, which will be a "something.txt" file
```

Similarly, if `destination` was a `Path`:

```
    stem, extension = os.path.splitext(destination)
...
        destination = Path(f"{stem} ({marker}){extension}")
```

using the newer `pathlib` becomes a one-line statement:

```
    destination = destination.with_stem(f"{stem} ({marker})")
```

## Complexity

As it stands, your script could suffer an \$O(N^2)\$ time complexity slowdown.

Consider dozens of directories, each with dozens of sub-directories, each with a dozens of sub-sub-directories, each with a `README.txt` file.

You script finds ...

1. the first `README.txt` file, and copies it.
2. the second `README.txt` file, notes it already exists, so writes `README (1).txt`.
3. the third `README.txt` file, notes it already exists, notes `README (1).txt` exists, so writes `README (2)`.txt
4. the fourth`README.txt` file, notes it already exists, notes `README (1).txt` exists, notes `README (2).txt` exists, so writes `README (3)`.txt

With N `README.txt` files, `.exists()` is called

- for `README.txt` N times,
- for `README (1).txt` N-1 times,
- for `README (2).txt` N-2 times,
- for `README (3).txt` N-3 times,
- for `README (4).txt` N-4 times,
- ...

... for a total of \$N (N - 1) / 2\$ calls.

If you maintained a counter for each source filename, you wouldn't need to start at 0 and check for existence of each variant of the filename.  You could simply start at the correct `marker` value.

## Reworked code:

```
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter

def selective_copy(destination: Path, source: Path, pattern: str) -> None:
    occurrences = Counter()

    for src in source.rglob(pattern):
        count = occurrences[src.name]

        stem = src.stem

        dst = destination / src.name
        if count:
            dst = dst.with_stem(f"{stem} ({count})")

        while dst.exists():
            count += 1
            dst = dst.with_stem(f"{stem} ({count})")

        shutil.copy(src, dst)

        occurrences[src.name] = count + 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    selective_copy(Path("to"), Path("from"), "*.txt")
```

Of course, replace the main code with your querying the user for the source, destination and pattern (or extension, to which you'd add the "*." prefix).

Comment: Can you think of a reason that the author chose to mix both styles in his chapter? Specifically, in his copying files and folders example, he uses both.

Comment: Inertia is usually the reason.  Also known as “technical debt”.

Comment: @ack Corrected.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is a straightforward and easy-to-understand solution. What follows are readability improvements.

---

If you are not going to use a part of a tuple, the standard way to indicate this is to use the variable name `_`:

```py
    for foldername, _, filenames in os.walk(basedir):
```

---

If the first line in a loop is a filtering step, it can be incorporated into the loop definition. Instead of

```py
        for filename in filenames:
            if not filename.endswith(extension):
                continue
            do_stuff()
```

write

```py
        for filename in [fn for fn in filenames if fn.endswith(extension)]:
            do_stuff()
```

The part in the parentheses is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It is a concise way of expressing lists. A more advanced alternative that needs less repetition of the variable `fn` uses the built-in function `filter`

```py
        for filename in filter(lambda fn: fn.endswith(extension), filenames):
            do_stuff()
```

---

Your `copy_increment()` function returns the correct file name when the file name does not already exist. The check for `destination.exists()` in `copy_extension()` is not necessary since that check happens within `copy_increment()`. Instead of

```py
            destination = newdir / filename
            if destination.exists():
                new_destination = copy_increment(destination)
                shutil.copy(file_path, new_destination)
            else: 
                shutil.copy(file_path, destination)
```

you could write

```py
            destination = copy_increment(newdir / filename)
            shutil.copy(file_path, destination)
```

---

After this line in `main()`

```py
            newdir = Path(user_destination)
```

shouldn't this folder be created if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: I'm not sure about the advice of incorporating the list comprehension into the loop definition. With the list comprehension, you are actually looping twice, once to build the list, and again to iterate over it

Comment: @C.Nivs: At the very least, it should be generator comprehension (using parentheses), but even then the longer line may hinder readability, especially if there are multiple filters.